# Can't update iframe's src in the viewer in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, model-view-controller, iframe

In shared folder of ASP.NET C#, I create a .cshtml which defines a button that can GET data from an API. I would like to generate an url and use it to update an iframe of a viewer.

```
        function callAPI(searchText) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/CallAPI',
                data: { Text: searchText },
                type: "GET",
                success: function (result) {
                    var data = JSON.stringify(result); // server response
                    found_data = data;
                    $(result).each(function () {
                        if (this.status == "found") {
                            alert("Found!" + data);
                            var frameElement = document.getElementById("SearchingMap");
                            lon = result.results[0].lon;
                            lat = result.results[0].lat;
                            new_searching_url = "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/styles/osm-bright-tw/#17/" + lat.toString() + "/" + lon.toString();
                            console.log(frameElement.src); // undefined
                            frameElement.src = new_searching_url;
                            console.log(frameElement.src); // "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/styles/osm-bright-tw/#17/.../..."
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Sorry! Not found");
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Sorry! Not found");
                }
            });
        }
```

However, the iframe in the viewer, which named SearchingMap.cshtml, doesn't updated.

```
@{ViewBag.Title = "SearchingMap";}
<div id="SearchingMap">
    <h3>Searching map</h3>
    <iframe src="http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/styles/osm-bright-tw/#10.01/25.0709/121.5008" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">Your browser doesn't support iframe.</iframe>
</div>
```

Why can't it work? How can I update the iframe of a viewer?

Comment: Take a good look at element `SearchingMap` and see if it has a `src` property. Or maybe if it is an iframe.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the `iframe` did not have the id `SearchingMap` so all javascript code fails because of this line:

```
var frameElement = document.getElementById("SearchingMap");
```

Just add this id, on your `iframe`

```
 <iframe id="SearchingMap" ...
```